# Execute a Bioconductor package command with input parameters given from the UI

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, bioconductor

I'm trying to run a command from a bioconductor package that takes as parameters the ones given from a user interface built with Shiny.
Heres is my code:

```
server.R

library(shiny)
library(RnBeads)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    input$submit
    rnb.options(input$identifiers_column)
    rnb.run.analysis(dir.reports=input$results_dir, sample.sheet=input$sample_annotation,data.dir=input$idat_dir,data.type="infinium.idat.dir")
  })


})
```

---

```
ui.R

library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Analysis options"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("MANDATORY FILES AND DIRECTORIES"),
      textInput('sample_annotation', label='Sample annotation sheet'),
      textInput("idat_dir", label='IDAT directory'),
      textInput("results_dir", label='Report directory'),
      actionButton("submit","Submit")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      img(src = "logo_bioestadistica.png",align='right'),
      h1('HELP',align='center'),
      p("IDAT directory path")
    )
  )
))
```

---

Here is the error message

```
Warning: Unhandled error in observer:  is invalid option
observe({
    input$submit
    rnb.run.analysis(dir.reports = input$results_dir, sample.sheet = input$sample_annotation, 
        data.dir = input$idat_dir, data.type = "infinium.idat.dir")
})
```

---

`rnb.run.analysis` must take the value of parameters given from the user interface and then be executed when pressing the "Submit" button.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the input values `input$identifiers_column`  cant see it on `server.r`. And also whats the purpose of outputing`input$submit` ?

Comment: I solved it myself but I'm not sure if this is the best way. It works, that's all.                                                                                                             library(shiny)
library(RnBeads)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    
  })
  observe({
    ntext()
    rnb.options(identifiers.column=input$identifiers_column)
    rnb.run.analysis(dir.reports=input$results_dir, sample.sheet=input$sample_annotation,data.dir=input$idat_dir,data.type="infinium.idat.dir")
  })
})